# convert a public key from BigInteger into a pem file in Java

Tags: java, public-key, pem

I can generate a pair of ecc private and public key pem files:

```
  KeyPair keyPair = generateECCKeyPair();
  ECPrivateKey priv = (ECPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
  ECPublicKey pub = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();  
  writePemFile(priv, "ECC PRIVATE KEY", "private.key");
  writePemFile(pub, "ECC PUBLIC KEY", "public.pem");
```

but now I hava a public ecc key in a BigInteger variable,how can I covert it or wrap it into the pem form, which contains header and footer, and bewtween them is the base64 encoded der form of the public key? Here If I'm wrong about the pem file, please correct me.

Comment: Use `Key.getEncoded()`, base64 encode it, split the output into 64 character lines, wrap and header and footer around it.

Comment: I know that's we have initialized the Key, but now if I only have the public key represented by a biginteger,then how to do that?